# Не получается вывести на страницу блок отформатированных тэгов html, созданный функцией js

Tags: javascript

Функция `createHtml` не выводит на страницу блок `div` с содержимым. Не могу понять, почему. Сама функция, как-будто, работает, то есть результат ее работы в переменной сохраняется. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. 
Код страницы:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Insert of HTML</title>


  </head>
  <body>

    <div class-"wrapper">
       <div class="for_insert"></div>      
    </div>

    <script>

      function createHtml() {

        return( 
          ` 
            <div>
              <h2>Заголовок</h2>
              <p>Абзац</p>
            </div>
          `
         ); // end return
      } // end createHtml

      var varCreateHtml = createHtml(); 
      document.getElementById("for_insert").innerHTML = varCreateHtml;  

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function createHtml() {
  return (` 
    <div>
      <h2>Заголовок</h2>
      <p>Абзац</p>
    </div>
  `);
}

const createHtmlVariable = createHtml();
document.querySelector('.for_insert').innerHTML = createHtmlVariable;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="for_insert"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В тэге `div class="for_insert"` надо поменять `class` на `id`, то есть тэг будет выглядеть так:  `div id="for_insert"`. Слово `class` - ключевое в javascript

Comment: То что "слово класс ключевое в js" - не имеет смысла, ибо элемент html не имеет к js никакого отношения.

Answer (score 1):

Ты запрашиваешь элемент через `getElementById`

```js
document.getElementById("for_insert")
```

Когда в html у тебя нету ида а есть только класс:
`<div class="for_insert"></div>`

Поменяй на:
`<div id="for_insert"></div>`